# Select List display range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

```
var myselect = document.getElementById("ageInYear"), year = new Date().getFullYear();
var gen = function(max){
    do{myselect.add(new Option(year--,max--),null);}
    while(max>0);}(100);
```

I have this code that display a Year list: from 1916 to 2015.
How am I able to get a range from 1915 to 1997 only?

Thanks guys!

Comment: try replacing `while(max>0);}(100);` with `while(max>0);}(82);`

Comment: and replace  year = 1997;

Comment: Or `year = new Date().getFullYear() - 18`

Comment: thanks! I tried it all, it's working now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myselect = document.getElementById("ageInYear");
for (i=1996; i>=1915;i--){
    myselect.add(new Option(i),null);
  }
```